# Insert canvas context to html string in new dynamically created window html

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, canvas, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extention to take full page screen shot. It is working fine while openening Image element in new window. But I need to display image in Canvas element to allow editing in canvas.

Here is the code for event listener of chrome.tabs.CaptureTab :

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request,sender,sendResponse) {

    if(Array.isArray(request.image)) {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        image,
        done = 0;

      canvas.width = request.width;
      canvas.height = request.height;

      for(var i = 0; i < request.image.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
          image = new Image();
          image.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(this, 0, request.image[i].position, this.width, this.height);
            if(++done == request.image.length) {
              screenshot = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

              var htmlCode = "<html><body>   Image here: <p><img border=\"2\" src=" + screenshot +"><p>  End Image </body></html>";
              var url = "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(htmlCode);
              chrome.tabs.create({url: url});

            }
          }
          image.src = request.image[i].image;
        })(i);
      }
    } else {
      var htmlCode = "<html><body>   Image here: <p><img border=\"2\" src=" + request.image +"><p>  End Image </body></html>";
      var url = "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(htmlCode);
      chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
      return;
    }

  });
```

Now, I tried :

```
var htmlCode = "<html><body>   Image here: <p><img border=\"2\" src=" + screenshot +"><p>  End Image <hr> " + canvas + " </body></html>";
```

It Gives : `[object HTMLCanvasELement]`

I need to embed this canvas element while creating the chrome tab

Comment: I would suggest that you need to call `appendChild(canvas)` if you want it to be this canvas. Otherwise you can include the html for a new canvas. See e.g. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the same using :

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.extension.getURL("../capturetab.html?tabImage=" + request.source )});
```

capturetab.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/visibletab.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

visibketab.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var imageblob = getUrlParameter('tabImage');

    //Set canvas attribute
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');    
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function(){
    // set width and height
    ctx.canvas.height = this.height;
    ctx.canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like   
    };
    img.src = imageblob;

});

function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```